# Percentile rank of column values - R

Tags: r

I am looking for a percentage rank for each value in a column.

It is quite easy in Excel, for example:

=RANK.EQ(A1,$A$1:$A$100,1)/COUNT($A$1:$A$100)

Returns a percent value in a new column that ranks the column I referred to above.

I have no problem finding quantile in R, but have not been able to find anything that accurately gives **percentile** for every single column value.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what percentage rank means ? If you want percentile from a column you can just do something along the lines of this `quantile(column_data, c(.30, .50, .95)) `  , this will return the 30th 50th and the 95th percentile.

Comment: `dplyr::ntile(..., 100)`

Comment: @Aditya, something like the screenshot I linked to below.  Quantile is great for lots of things, but i need specific percentages for each value.

https://ibb.co/w4fNfCs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using the data in your picture:

```
> Cost.Per.Kilo <- c(rep(c(6045170, 5412330, 3719760, 3589220), each=2), 
                     3507400)
> Cost.Per.Kilo
[1] 6045170 6045170 5412330 5412330 3719760 3719760 3589220 3589220 3507400
> CPK.rank <- rank(Cost.Per.Kilo, ties.method="min")
> CPK.rank
[1] 8 8 6 6 4 4 2 2 1
> round(CPK.rank/length(CPK.rank) * 100)
[1] 89 89 67 67 44 44 22 22 11
```

In your picture you seem to have divided the ranks by 10, but there are only 9 values. That is why these percentages do not match.

Comment: Perfect!  That works exactly as I need it to - thank you very much!